# How to load player sprite in runtime. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I need to create sprites in runtime what you can move and animate not in unity editor. How that is done? I'm lost here.

Small question I know! Thanks for help :)

I've tried creating sprite first :

```
    char_sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Art/GamesPlusJames_RPG-Character_0");
```

Should I Instantiate it somehow to screen and how?

Answer (score 0):

Since you talked about creating, here is how you could do it

```
       //Create a new gameObject
        GameObject char_obj = new GameObject("char");
        //Add an SpriteRenderer component
        SpriteRenderer char_sprite = char_obj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        //Load the sprite and assign it
        char_sprite.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Art/GamesPlusJames_RPG-Character_0");
```

If you only need to change the sprite. You can change it by accessing the [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) component and change its sprite.